# zip iterator with openmp won't go parallel

Tags: iterator, parallel-processing, openmp

I am trying to use a zip iterator (from either boost or thrust library) with openmp.  My goal is to have a for_each loop that will process things in parallel through openmp.

Using the example from the boost documentation:

```c
#pragma omp parallel for
std::for_each(
    boost::make_zip_iterator(
    boost::make_tuple(beg1, beg2)
),
    boost::make_zip_iterator(
    boost::make_tuple(end1, end2)
),
    zip_func()
);
```

However, this doesn't appear to run in parallel.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have to do is either use `omp parallel for` followed by a a for loop, use gcc `__gnu_parallel::for_each` as was previously suggested or explicitly partition your iteration range (notice the absence of `for` in the pragma):

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
int tid = omp_get_thread_num();
int n   = omp_get_num_threads();
auto nbeg1, nbeg2, nend1, nend2  = ... // create n chunks of work, each thread takes one chunk
std::for_each(
  boost::make_zip_iterator(boost::make_tuple(nbeg1, nbeg2)),
  boost::make_zip_iterator(boost::make_tuple(nend1, nend2)),
  zip_func() );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert in OpenMP. I think that, to use a pragma omp for, OpenMP waits a complete for construction, for instance:

```
#pragma omp parallel for 
{    
for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
```

Besides, I think that std:for_each is implemented using OpenMP.

See http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/parallel_mode.html

Comment: gcc's parallel mode has to be explicitly enabled. So unless you either define the relevant header or use the __gnu_parallel namespace, it will not go into that codepath.